# ChangeNotifierProvider&&ChangeNotifierProvider.value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I cant understand the difference between ChangeNotifierProvider and ChangeNotifierProvider.value,
and when use every case
ChangeNotifierProvider :-

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
       create: (context) => ProductsProvider(),
```

ChangeNotifierProvider.value :-

```
return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: products[i],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ChangeNotifierProvider:**
It creates a new instance of some class from where you want to consume data

**ChangeNotifierProvider.value**
In case if you already have a instance which has some data loaded previously and you want to consume the previously loaded data then you need to use `ChangeNotifierProvider.value`

Comment: what happened if I use ChangeNotifierProvider.value and I don't have an instance previously?

Comment: Just pass a newly created instance. It will work like ChangeNotifierProvider

Comment: so i always use ChangeNotifierProvider.value ?

Answer (score 0):

`ChangeNotifierProvider` will create an instance of the class you are providing.

`ChangeNotifierProvider.value` will provide a pre Instantiated object